# How to finish this special series for the error function on (0,1]?

Tags: power-series, hyperbolic-functions, error-function

Inspired by the Bürmann's expansion of the error function find on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) I found the begin of an expansion also using $e^{-x^2}$ :

### Explanation for $x\in(0,1]$:

We start with a well-know inequality for $x\geq 0$ :

$$\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)\geq 0$$

The problem is the maximum is not an integer easily reachable so using  a limit we divide by $x$ to get :

$$g(x)=\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)}{x}$$

The maximum define as a limit is at $x\to 0$

Now we use a famous function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ .For that we multiply the function $f$ by the limit a zero of $g$ and we substract this quantity to $g(x)$ we get :

$$h(x)=\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(-1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)e^{-x^{2}}$$

Again the maximum is not easily reachable so now we divide by $x^2$, substract and we have :

$$r\left(x\right)=\frac{\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(-1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)e^{-x^{2}}}{x^{2}}-e^{-x^{2}}\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)$$

As I have some problem with Desmos I have only this .

In fact I can pursue it the next step is :

$$\frac{\frac{\frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)}{x}-\left(-1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)e^{-x^{2}}}{x^{2}}-e^{-x^{2}}\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)}{x^{2}}-\left(-\frac{3}{10}+\frac{8}{15}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)e^{-x^{2}}$$

---

---

How to finish it and justify it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are very welcome on this question .

Comment: The next term is $-5/63+16/105*1/\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: The series may have the form $\frac{\text{erf}(x)-\tanh(x)}{x^n}+e^{-x^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n\pi^\frac{n+a}2 x^{-n}$ with the [expanded form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28%28erf%28x%29-tanh%28x%29%29%2Fx-%282%2Fs-1%29e%5E-x%5E2%29%2Fx%5E2-e%5E-x%5E2+%28%284%2F3%29%2Fs-2%2F3%29%29%2Fx%5E2-%288%2F15*1%2Fs-3%2F10%29e%5E-x%5E2%29)

Comment: Welcome back to the site !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks you are kind !